# How can I get the ID of ImageButton for javascript, if the ImageButton was created in code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, code-behind, imagebutton

I created an ImageButton in code buhind-

```
var img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "Del" + i.ToString();
img.ImageUrl = "images/1395958363_meanicons_57.png";
img.Width = 48;
img.Height = 38;
img.OnClientClick = "javascript:void(DeleteBook())";

Label1.Controls.Add(img);
```

Now I need to get the ID of the ImageButton. Can anyone help me with this?

P.S The ImageButton was creates in "for", so I don't know how mutch ImageButton I have and what is them ID

Comment: please correct orthography in your title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the `UniqueID` property?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the img.ID into the javascript DeleteBook() function directly.

or better yet you can pass this directly eg: OnClientClick ="DeleteBook(this)"